# Angular PWA not detected inside GitLab CI pages

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, gitlab, progressive-web-apps

I am Creating angular pwa web app. I am deploying angular web app to gitlab-pages using gitlab-ci.yml CI. My question is after deployment of angular web app PWA is not installable. Can Any one spot whats going wrong here.

https://grdtech.gitlab.io/pizza-shop/

Above link is live deployed angualar pwa inside gitlab pages using gitlab-ci.yml CI. But in this site pwa is not detected and install prompts not coming.

**gitlab-ci.yml file**

```
image: node:12.19.0

pages:
   cache:
   paths:
      - node_modules/
script:
   - npm install -g @angular/cli@11.0.2
   - npm install
   - npm run buildProd

artifacts:
   paths:
     - public
only:
   - master
   - pages
```

**manifest.webmanifest**

```
{
   "name": "createpizza",
   "short_name": "createpizza",
   "theme_color": "#1976d2",
   "background_color": "#fafafa",
   "display": "standalone",
   "scope": "./",
   "start_url": "./",
   "icons": [
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   },
   {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you are not deploying a production build. By default PWA are only applied while building for production. You can do so using

```
ng build --prod
```

To make sure a project is a dev or a production build you can use `Augury` which will only work in a dev environment

[Augury docs](https://augury.rangle.io/)

Comment: actually in `package.json` file I am adding new script called `"buildProd": "ng build --base-href=https://grdtech.gitlab.io/pizza-shop/",` and as you have said i had not added --prod flag there.. so I added --prod flag, and as you said service-worker is applied and works. Thank you. Sometime little thing we can not figure out. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Can you give more details about `Augury`, ?

Comment: `Augury` is a browser extension used to debug Angular applications. I updated my answer in order to add the docs @GaurangDhorda